# Elementary Set Theory Questions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm just trying to seek some clarification while I'm working through a set theory chapter of a book. I have arrived at the following question:

"Decide if the following statements are true or false. Explain"

1) $\{(x,y): x-1=0\}$ is a subset of $\{(x,y):x^2-x = 0\}$

2) $\{(x,y): x^2-x = 0\}$ is a subset of $\{(x,y): x-1=0\}$

My current thinking has me believing that 1) must be true and that 2) must be false, but my explanation is where I'm a bit shaky. If I plot $\{(x,y): x-1=0\}$ on the $xy$-plane, I would get a line $x = 1$ whose points are all elements of $\{(x,y): x^2-x=0\}$. Of course, in making this conclusion, I had to assume that $y$ is an element of the set of real numbers. Is this assumption valid? Why or why not, and if not, how do I go about answering this question?

Thanks

Comment: You did jump to thinking about "the $xy$-plane" although nothing in the snippet of the assignment explicitly says $y$ (or $x$ for that matter) is a real number.  Probably this is meant to be implied (and maybe the section of the book where the exercise is given reinforces the assumption), but as a technical matter the domain of $y$ values does not need to be the real numbers to reason as you do (we just need some consistent assumption about possibilities for $y$ in both sets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to jump into straight lines for this question! Consider this 
approach:

**Problem:**

> Define $A=\{(x,y): x-1=0\}$ and $B=\{(x,y):x^2-x = 0\}$. We wish to check if $A$ is a subset of $B$.

Can you visualize what the elements of A will be like? Notice that there's no constraint on the value of $y$. The definition only says that $x=1$. So, any element of the form $(1,y)$ will belong to $A$.

Now, let's determine the elements of set $B$. Here again, there's no constraint on the value of $y$, whereas the value of $x=0$ or $1$ only.Hence, any element of the form $(0,y)$ or $(1,y)$ belongs to $B$.

Notice that $B$ contains some extra elements of the form $(0,y)$ which do not belong to $A$, and that $B$ contains all the elements that $A$ already contained (of the form $(1,y)$).

Hence, $A$ is a subset of $B$, proved.

---

Can you similarly do the proof for (2) now?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, when you want to determine if a set $A$ is a subset of another set, $B$, you take any element of $A$, and show that it belongs to $B$.

In other words, you want to determine if $(x,y) \in A \implies (x,y) \in B$ is a true statement.

Define $A = \{(x,y): x-1=0\}$ and $B = \{(x,y):x^2-x = 0\}$.

Then, take any element of $A$, say $(x_1,y_1)$. Now, we know that for this element, $x_1-1 = 0$. Looking at some element of $B$, $(x_2,y_2)$, it's the case that $x_2^2-x_2 = x_2(x_2-1)=0$.

But if $x_1-1=0$, then surely $x_1(x_1-1) = x_1^2-x_1=0$, and so $(x_1,y_1) \in B$.

Can you apply this reasoning to the second part? Note that if it isn't true, usually your best course of action is to find a counterexample.

Or, to save you calculation in this case, think more generally about what you are being asked to prove, and also what you now know. You now know that $A \subseteq B$, and are being asked if $B \subseteq A$. If this were to be true, what would it imply about $A$ and $B$, which can easily be shown to be untrue?

With regards your question about real numbers, it is not necessary to know what type of numbers $x$ and $y$ are. Approaching questions like this by trying to picture it in the real $xy$-plane may prove to be very hard with differently, more complexly defined sets, and although it works fine here visually, it can be difficult to convey mathematically. (A picture is not a proof).

If the question has just been given as you have given it, I personally would assume that both $A$ and $B$ belong to the same superset, i.e. that they're both subsets of the real numbers, or the natural numbers etc. You may find you get different answers to these questions if this is not the case, and you may want to experiment with this.